# Error creating Jenkins Blue Ocean pipeline: Invalid name for SCM configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm trying to add a new pipeline in Jenkins Blue Ocean, but I'm encountering an error when attempting to create it. The first step involves selecting GIT as the SCM option. In the second step, I enter the URL: user@server:repo-name.git. I have added the public key to GIT to establish a connection, and the connection is successful. However, when I try to create the pipeline, I receive the following error message:

```
Error:
An unknown error has occurred. You may try again.
Message: Failed to create pipeline
Field: scmConfig.name
Code: INVALID
Message: user@server:repo-nam is not a valid name.
```

I have confirmed that the URL and credentials are correct.
Thank you in advance for your help!